# When I create a new ASP.NET 4 web application, the web.config file is almost empty

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0

When I create a new ASP.NET 4 web application, the web.config file is almost empty. What happened to all the configuration elements that were there prior to ASP.NET 4?

Comment: They're probably assumed with default values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a good post explaining it.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/08/25/clean-web-config-files-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx

"The **new .NET 4 machine.config file now** automatically registers all of the ASP.NET tag sections, handlers and modules that we’ve added over the years, including the functionality for:

ASP.NET AJAX
ASP.NET Dynamic Data
ASP.NET Routing (which can now be used for both ASP.NET WebForms and ASP.NET MVC)
ASP.NET Chart Control (which now ships built-into ASP.NET V4)
What this means is that when you create a new “Empty ASP.NET application” project in VS 2010, you’ll find that the new default application-level web.config file is now clean and simple:"

Answer (score 0):

Most of the configuration settings are now used from the the machine.config instead of your web.config. Apart form that I think you must have selected "empty web application" from the menu when you created your application.